# Диаграмма частотного распределения на c#

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Имеется набор данных, отображаемый в столбце DataGridView. Необходимо в ChartControl построить диаграмму распределения, например, как на изображении.

[image: Диаграмма частотного распределения]

Диаграмму хотел сделать приблизительно следующим образом:

```
for (int k = 0; k < OutputDataGridView.Rows.Count-1; k++)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Double.Parse(OutputDataGridView[0,k].Value.ToString()), frequencyValue);
}

chart1.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending, "X", "Series1");

chart1.DataManipulator.Group("First", 0.1, IntervalType.Number, "Series1");
```

Возник вопрос, как наиболее адекватно подсчитать частоту, с которой встречается значение в наборе данных, чтоб отображать ее по оси Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, я тупанул по-страшному, ибо, судя по всему, все оказалось проще, чем думал поначалу. 
В качестве `frequencyValue` в `AddXY(...)` указал единицу, а в `chart1.DataManipulator.Group(...)` вместо формулы группировки `"First"` - `"Sum"`. 
Диаграмма вроде отображается как нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знал, что стандартный `ChartControl` такой умный :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `Linq` и не возиться с циклами и счетчиками:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Value, (k, v) => new { Value = k, Count = v.Count() });
```

где `Value` - свойство, по которому вы хотите сгруппировать набор данных.

Вместо анонимного типа можно преобразовывать сразу в `DataPoint`:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Value, (k, v) => new DataPoint(k, v.Count()));
```